# Add an overlay pattern (png) over a div

Tags: html, css, overlay

Is there a way using HTML to add an overlay using an image url in a specific div?

I managed to make something work using CSS :

```
#myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;

}
#myDiv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

But it is a bit tricky. When I tried to do the same for other divs, it did not work. So for instance I have this CSS code for a div :

```
.hi-icon-wrap img
{
    border-radius: 80px;
    width: 153px;
    height: 153px;
    margin:2%;
}
```

and I want to add an overlay. I am using this script but with no success:

```
.hi-icon-wrap img:before {
  background: transparent url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

and I also tested that :

```
.hi-icon-wrap img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

UPD:

HTML script:

```
<div class="hi-icon-wrap" class="hi-icon-wrap img" style="text-align: center">
    <img src="image.png">
 </div>
```

Comment: You're not setting `content: '';` etc on the one you're having trouble with

Comment: I updated the question. It did not work either.  @AndyHolmes

Comment: Your edit isn't correct either. You've missed the `img`

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you posted your HTML.

Comment: @AndyHolmes It does not work for me.

Comment: Let me show you a link with the fix to your issue and a better way of doing it, hang on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use overlay on `div` element and not on `img`

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#myDiv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
  opacity: .8;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/D6E7FF/ffffff">
</div>
```

Edit: You can't use `:after` or `:before` on `img` as you can see here [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/473/) because image elements don't contain text or have descendants, so what you can do is wrap img in `div` for example and then you get this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/474/)

Comment: It works for the div but I want the overlay only for the images there.

Comment: You can't (shouldn't) use `:before` or `:after` on `img`, "Image tags are self-closing (<tag />) tags because they contain no content. Since they do not contain any content, no generated content can be appended (::after) or prepended (::before) to the existing content."

Comment: How can I make it work for the images only then? JS is the only solution? @Nenad Vracar

Comment: Why can't you just wrap img in div?

Comment: I have already created the HTML code. I will have to put divs everywhere. I want the optimal way. Your answer was very interesting regarding the img tags.

Comment: This is working example with html you provided https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/475/.

Comment: I changed the one you posted before a bit. I just have to add a div : http://codepen.io/apolosisk/pen/MyVbJy

Comment: http://apolosiskos.co.uk/apolo.html Here is the actual site. So, I will need to use my version. I have just seen yours. The last one... I will have to create a div between the hi-icon-wrap and img I guess.

Comment: If you don't want to change html you maybe you could do this with js https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/478/